# No indentation when displaying an icon in an NSMenuItem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmenuitem

I am trying to add an icon to only one NSMenuItem item but it is indenting the icon and text by 1 level.

I tried to set the setIndentationLevel to "0" but that doesn't work.

An example of what I am trying to achieve can be seen in the Wireless status bar menu where the tickbox is displayed against the current WiFi your connected to e.g. http://cl.ly/2T362b2I0f1G1O3b3G3z

Any tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That check mark is the menu item's "on" state image. NSMenuItem includes methods for setting its state and the image displayed for each of its states. (By default, the "on" image is that check mark, the "off" state image is blank and the "mixed" state image is a dash.)

Comment: Thanks! I looked up NSMenuItem and found `setState` and set it to `NSOnState`